# Hurwitz integers and $F_4$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations, lattices, quadratic-forms

The Hurwitz integers are
$$
\mathcal H=
\{a+bi+cj+dk:a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Z\;\text{ or } \;a,b,c,d\in \tfrac12+\mathbb Z\}. 
$$
I want to know if there is a formula, for $m\in\mathbb Z$, for the number of elements $\alpha\in\mathcal H$ such that $|\alpha|^2=m$.

This is equivalent to known the number of vectors $v$ in the lattice $F_4$ such that $\|v\|^2=m$.

I think this formula already exist but I can find it. An appropiate reference would be appreciated. Thanks.-.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/84897/proofs-of-jacobis-four-square-theorem/87272#87272

Comment: see http://oeis.org/A004011  and  http://oeis.org/A004011/b004011.txt

Comment: perfect answer! nice proof. Thank you.-.