# How many distinct quaternions have a given prime norm $p$?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, quaternions

I seem to recall that the answer is $p + 1$, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/q/84897/297

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "quaternions" and "distinct".
If you mean quaternions $a + b{\bf i} + c{\bf j} + d{\bf k}$,
with $a,b,c,d$ all integers, then you're asking to count solutions of
$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 = p$, which by
[Jacobi's
four squares theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_four-square_theorem) is $8$ times the sum of positive divisors of $p$,
i.e. $8(p+1)$.  If you then identify quaternions ${\bf q}$ with ${\bf qu}$
or ${\bf uq}$ (but not both!) where $\bf u$ is one of the eight units
$\pm 1, \pm{\bf i}, \pm{\bf j}, \pm{\bf k}$, then there are $p+1$
distinct solutions as desired.